# Excel for Microsoft 365: Change Width of Columns Based on Column Name in Header Row

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I am using Excel for Microsoft 365.

On the first worksheet, I have recorded a macro to adjust column widths and row heights. I then switched to the second worksheet and ran this macro and realized I have the problem described below.

Each worksheet contains at least one (maybe multiple) columns whose column name in the header row (row 1) contains the string "foo". The locations of these columns vary from worksheet to worksheet.

There are some steps I perform on all columns. These steps work fine. However, there's an extra step I'd like to perform on the "foo" column(s). Specifically, I'd like to change the width of those columns to 30. Since the locations of these columns vary from worksheet to worksheet, this isn't so straightforward to do.

Here is VBA code that illustrates the problem:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ' This part works.
    Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"
    Cells.Select

    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With

    Columns("A:A").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 100

    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    ' The problem starts here.
    ' How may I do this for all columns whose column name in the header row contains "foo"?
    ' There are an arbitrary number of such columns and their locations vary from worksheet to worksheet.
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 30
    Columns("L:L").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 30

    ' The rest of this macro works fine.
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit

    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
    End With

    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
End Sub
```

In this code, I set columns G and L to have width 30. Rather than hardcode the columns, how may I change this code to set the width to 30 of any column whose column name (in the header row) contains "foo"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over all columns, and check whether the top row contains "foo":

```
For Each myColumn In ActiveSheet.Columns
    If InStr(1, LCase(myColumn.Cells(1, 1)), "foo") <> 0 Then
        myColumn.ColumnWidth = 30
    End If
Next
```